# stm32 pin assignment in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, stm32, stm32f1

I have a multi-cooker which is not working so I decided to use its PCB for my project. It has an STM32f103c8t7 chip on it. some LEDs and a buzzer and a display, which I may not need though. I have found the connection between chip pins and elements on the board (for example the buzzer is connected to the pin number 13, "PA3") but I have a problem. since this is my first try with stm32 in arduino, I don't know how to name the pins of chip. I have tried PA3, 13 and D13 but none of them seem to to useful. what should I do to make the board buzz?

the buzzer is ok and works fine. Actually one of the buzzer's pin is connected to 12 V and another pin is connected to a transistor which its base is connected to the chip.
this is the code that I have tried:

```
void setup() {

  pinMode(PA3, OUTPUT);
//   pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
//   pinMode(D13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  
  digitalWrite(PA3, HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);
  digitalWrite(PA3, LOW);
  delay(delayTime);

//   digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
//   delay(delayTime);
//   digitalWrite(13, LOW);
//   delay(delayTime);

//   digitalWrite(D13, HIGH);
//   delay(delayTime);
//   digitalWrite(D13, LOW);
//   delay(delayTime);
}
```

[image]

Comment: why not PA13? https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/master/variants/Generic_F103Cx/variant.h#L30

Comment: because the datasheet said so. I will upload that part to my question now

Comment: physical chip pin numbers have no meaning in software

Comment: so how may I address this specific pin?

Comment: visit the link in my first comment?

Comment: please help me to understand that link you have sent. what label can be used for pin number 13 and 46 respectively?

Comment: physical chip pin numbers have no meaning in software. but on the pinout picture you see that it is PA3

Comment: but as I said, PA3 is not working for me.

Comment: then it is not that pin